# How to get the distance of a BEACON from a Device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am trying to get accurate distance of BEACON from an Android Device using "getDistance()" function.

When we try to run the parameter "txPower" for the same, we get an error "minimum SDK Requirements 27". When we try to run forcefully on Version below 27 (Oreo 8.1), then it crashes abruptly. So we're trying to figure out if there is a way to run the parameter "txPower" on versions below 27 successfully to "getDistance()"

Comment: What SDK are you using to access txPower and getDistance()?  If you show your code it might make that clear.

Comment: We are using SDK version 24 but to get txPower, it shows error that minimum SDK requirement is 27.

Comment: What third party beacon SDK or library are you using?  Android SDKs do not have any built-in beacon APIs with a getDistance() call.